# How to print all leafs in binary search tree with java?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

One of my friend ask a question about binary search tree section in data structure and I didn't have any solution.
Consider we have a binary search tree class that have insert and `printlistleafs` method. When we add new node to this tree all leafs should be point each other. When we call `printlistleafs` method program should print all leafs node from first side to last side. 
see this photo to understanding the question:

[image: structure of binary search tree]

at last when in this structure we want to add new node all pointer should update.

[image: when we add new node to this structure tree should be update]

Please help me to writing this program in java.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a root node, the root of your BinaryTree and a list of leaves. For each node that you add, you proceed to an insertion.

For each insert, you have two actions to perform: update the tree and update the list.

1. I assume you know how to update the tree.
2. In order to update the list, there are only two cases to look after

   - The parent node is in the list -> the new node replaces it, you can directly get the references of the parent and update them (and their neighbours).
   - The parent node isn't in the list (e.g. had one child already) -> the new node is to be *inserted* in the list. Since your list is sorted, you simply need to find the previous or next leaf by navigating your tree up-left or up-right and redirect the references.

Comment: the ability that all leaves should be have is iterate from a one leave to another leafs.from left to right side . user can be Scrolling on leafs.

Comment: I completely reviewed my answer based on your comment.